# Transitioning AVplayer in modal transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, avplayer

We are trying to achieve the same effect as within the Facebook app regarding tapping on a video in the feed and transitioning the same video at the same time to a modal view.

How do you transition an AVplayer from a uitableviewcell to a new instance of a uiviewcontroller seamlessly?

Answer (score 5):

I achieved this by implemnting the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and using my own custom animator object, which conforms to the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol.

I used https://github.com/recruit-mp/RMPZoomTransitionAnimator as a reference, with a few modifications to move an actual view (not a snapshot) between source and destination `UIViewControllers` :

Within the animator object, using the animator object's delegate methods for "source frame" and "destiation frame" and "playerView", all which are implemented on the "to" and "from" view controllers, I grab the view containing the playing video, grab it's start frame, it's end frame, and properly animate the view from its start frame to the frame it will end up being located at on the "to" view controller.

Upon completion of the transition, I then add the playing video `UIView` as a subview to the destination view controller, so that it becomes part of the "to" view controller's view, available for interacting with, etc.

Comment: Downvoting your answer as it has nothing to do with transitioning seamlessly between view controllers with videos as the OP has stated in his inquiry.

Comment: Stephen, it has everything to do with it - I used this protocol to allow me access the frame of the AVPlayerView on the "from" view controller and animate it to a final position on the "to" view controller, which both are accessible within the animator object used by the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol.  

I am the OP, and you can see an example of how I used my own answer in our app which you can download at comedy.com.

I don't think you thought much before down-voting ... can you be more clear and give us some valid argument as to why?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't realize you were the OP.  I don't recall you ever elaborating on the answer as you did the past two paragraphs. If that was there before, I must have missed it. I will retract it. I have a question with you guys' experience with passing the player, but I will create another thread in SO about it. Feel free to chip in with any ideas.

Comment: Hey @StephenPaul, its all good, I was a little down that day, so I'm sorry for the kinda pissy answer :)  Well in any case, I'm happy to help where I can :) Just let me know!

Comment: I can't get this to work with `AVPlayerViewController`. Looks like the video view has the final, full-screen size all along the transition (i.e., it does not support animating the size of the video). I think I need to ditch `AVPlayerViewController` and use n `AVPlayerLayer` directly...